# Java - String.contains() behaves oddly

Tags: java, windows, string

this snippet of code works fine on my development machine (Windows 7 installed on VirtualBox jre 8 using Netbeans IDE), but on another machine (Windows 7 jre 8) always returns true.
It should only find files with a name like "town_house.html" instead it always returns true for every file in the folder.Running the jar file from prompt I don't get any exceptions.
Maybe it's just a trivial error I usually program in C/C++ ... any idea?

```
for(File f : files)
        {
            if(f.toString().contains("_") && 
               f.toString().contains(".html")){
                System.out.print("Processing file: " + f.getName()+ "\n");
                String[] fileSplit = f.getName().split("_");
                towns.add(fileSplit[0]);

            }
        }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are testing in `file.toString()` and splitting on `file.getName()`.  I would first eliminate this inconsistency and try again.

Comment: for(File f : files)
        { // here print the fileName and check what it prints

Comment: Ensure both machines use the same char encoding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are checking `toString()` instead of `getName()` - maybe the directory path contains an underscore.

Try this instead (note also simplified test):

```
for(File f : files) {
    if (f.getName().matches(".*_.*\\.html")) {
        System.out.print("Processing file: " + f.getName()+ "\n");
        String[] fileSplit = f.getName().split("_");
        towns.add(fileSplit[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: wild guess but makes sense!

Comment: you are right the path contains an underscore on my friend's machine, because I copied it naming it "folder"_12_5  thanks a lot

Comment: @assylias There's a special `Read mind` button on the user profile page that only moderators have access to.